# How can I suggest a tag synonym on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I tried suggesting synonyms for certain tags in Stack Overflow. But it always says:

> The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a synonym!

I am not getting this at all. Can anyone explain what is meant by "tag must exist in the system"? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no need to have a synonym that's never actually been used, so the system won't allow you to attempt to create one.

The purpose of synonyms is to link tags that are used to mean the exact same thing, not to predict every way a person in the future might conceivably type the tag.

Comment: hmmm.. thanks for your replay.. what i tried was ....adding synonyms for codeigniter as CI... which i think lots of people use it.. but turns out  that is not  used much.. anyways thanks again . :)